# null return Intent on android programming

Tags: java, android

I write a simple program in android studio and create an object from Intent.
but i don't know why it return null ??

in the MainActivity.java I send userName and password to ProfileActivity.java.but Log.i shows null!
but Token is not null

> com.example.sayres.myapplication2.ProfileActivity: onCreate User Name:
>   null Password: null Token: 22546874569

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String INTENT_USER_NAME_KYE = "user_name_key";
    public static final String INTENT_USER_PASSWORD_KYE = "password_key";

    protected final String TAG = "====>";

    private EditText editTextUserName, editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonLogin, buttonExit;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initView();


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnLogin:
                getUserInfo();
                break;
            case R.id.btnExit:
                finish();
                break;
        }


    }



    private void initView() {
        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        buttonExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonExit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private void getUserInfo() {
        String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        editTextUserName.setText("");
        editTextPassword.setText("");


        String msg = "";
        if (userName.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            msg = "Insert UserName And Password !!!";
        } else {
            msg = "Welcome " + userName;
            // TODO: 1/7/2017 go to ProfileActivity !!!

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("INTENT_USER_NAME_KYE", userName);
            intent.putExtra("INTENT_USER_PASSWORD_KYE", password);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("user_token", "22546874569");
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "UserName= " + userName + "\t" + "Password= " + password);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

ProfileActivity.java:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = ProfileActivity.class.getName();
    private TextView textViewUserName, textViewPassword, textViewAge, textViewSex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
//        initviews();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String userName = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_USER_NAME_KYE);
        String password = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_USER_PASSWORD_KYE);

//        System.out.println("User Name iS:"+userName);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String user_token = extras.getString("user_token");

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate " + "User Name: " + userName + " Password: " + password + " Token: " + user_token);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
intent.putExtra("INTENT_USER_NAME_KYE", userName);
intent.putExtra("INTENT_USER_PASSWORD_KYE", password);
```

You're using a literal `"INTENT_USER_NAME_KYE"` as the intent key, not the value of the `INTENT_USER_NAME_KYE` field you're using for reading the extras:

```
String userName = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_USER_NAME_KYE);
String password = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.INTENT_USER_PASSWORD_KYE);
```

Remove the `"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("user_token", "22546874569");
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

above code removing intent values(extra values) which you set in intent so you should always choose either intent or bundle to pass your data to another activity.

try with below code it should work

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("INTENT_USER_NAME_KYE", userName);
                    intent.putExtra("INTENT_USER_PASSWORD_KYE", password);
                    intent.putExtra("user_token", "22546874569");
startActivity(intent);
```